# how to set remotedirectory in sftp outboud gateway in java-spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="sftpOutBound"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"   expression="payload" command="put" request-channel="outboundFtpChannel"
    remote-directory="/tmp/tsiftp" reply-channel="sftpReplyChannel"/>
```

with the above xml, i can send files and get reply . In java, how to set the remote directory in SftpOutboundGateway .If I use SftpMessageHandler,is there any possibility to get reply.Commented code is transferring files but no reply.

```
 @Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundFtpChannel")
public MessageHandler transfertoPeopleSoft(){
 /*  SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
     handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("/tmp/tsiftp"));
     return handler;*/
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway( sftpSessionFactory(), "put", "/tmp/tsiftp");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("sftpReplyChannel");
    return sftpOutboundGateway;
}

 Exception I am getting is
   exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [/tmp/tsiftp] @0: EL1070E: Problem parsing left operand
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The remote directory for the `SftpOutboundGateway` can be configured by the `SftpRemoteFileTemplate` and its:

```
/**
 * Set the remote directory expression used to determine the remote directory to which
 * files will be sent.
 * @param remoteDirectoryExpression the remote directory expression.
 */
public void setRemoteDirectoryExpression(Expression remoteDirectoryExpression) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rft

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) for improvements on the matter.

I know that `Expression` variant isn't so useful because you need to use `SpelExpressionParser` or just `LiteralExpression` just for simple dir variant.

Comment: thank you @artem, I will try that. Is there any option to delete the local file after transferring for put command.

Comment: M-m-m. No, there is no. You can do that as a service activator after `SftpOutboundGateway` performing simple `File.delete()` operation. The original file you can store in the message headers do not lose it in between.